# Extract statistical information from Wikipedia article

Tags: python, sparql, wikipedia, information-retrieval, dbpedia

I'm currently extracting data from DBpedia articles using a SPARQLWrapper for python, but I can't seem to find how to extract the number of watchers (and other statistical information) for a given article.

Is there an easy way to achieve this? I don't mind if it's through DBpedia, or directly through wikipedia (using wget, for example).

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: If you're considering using Wikipedia, take a look at the [MediaWiki API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page); it's probably easier to use than screen scraping.

Comment: What “other statistical information” are you looking for?

Comment: @mc10 In general, yes, but specifically the number of watchers is not available there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It shell be prohibited to get the number of watchers for every arbitrary article, as it is considered to be a security leak if everyone could find unwatched pages. For example, only privileged users have access to [Special:Unwatched Pages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special%3aUnwatchedPages). There is a [toolserver tool](http://toolserver.org/~mzmcbride/cgi-bin/watcher.py) (which has access to the DB) showing the number of watchers, but it is restricted to pages with more than 30 watchers [for the same reasons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User%3aMZMcBride/watcher) - at least unauthenticated.

The [MediaWiki query API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aQuery) exposes <s>only</s> mostly [content and status information](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aProperties) about articles, though you can query and evaluate the [public logs](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aLogevents) or [revision histories](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aProperties#revisions_.2F_rv) as well to get statistical data about (public) user actions. For more stats about the Wikimedia sites you may have a look at [Meta:Statistics](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Statistics), where various data sources (mostly http://stats.wikimedia.org/) and visualisations of them are listed.